# Run program after finish ssh connection

Tags: debian, ssh, background-process

How do I connect to ssh debian and running a program and let it continue to run after you finish my connection through ssh.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply `nohup` the program you are starting and put it in the background akin to:

```
nohup someShellScript.sh > nohup.out 2>&1 &
```

**EDIT as per Thor's suggestion**

From non-interactive session:

```
ssh <hostname> "nohup someShellScript.sh > nohup.out 2>&1 &"
```

Comment: Remember to quote the command, i.e. if the above is `cmd=...` then use `ssh remote "$cmd"`.

Answer (score 3):

There are at least two way to do that

1) `nohup` command as already mentioned. Wikipedia has an article about [nohup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup)

2) There are two popular terminal multiplexers `screen` and `tmux` They enable a number of terminals, each running a separate program. There are a lot of tutorials and how-to about both tools on the Internet, just google